# How to create drop down menu in top of website using jquery, html, css in my exist website

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to add drop down menu with multi level as show in below image

[image]

I want easy way to create it in my current bootstrap website.

Help me !! :)

Comment: So you want to get full solution without doing anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi Level Drop Down Menu Using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647297/multi-level-drop-down-menu-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple way for add drop down menu to add in your website.

Check my article

[jQuery Drop down menu](http://www.jquery.ml/2017/05/jquery-css3-and-html5-simple-drop-down.html)

```js
$(function() {
  $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
  $('nav li').hover(function() {
    $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font: 400 12px/1.625 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #444;
  background: #F0F0ED;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  overflow: auto;
  background: #33363C;
  border-top: 5px solid #2F3135;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #04A4CC;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 50px 5px;
}

#logo img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 36px;
}

#view-tut {
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 10px 50px 5px;
}

#view-tut ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#view-tut ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#view-tut ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #04A4CC;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#view-tut ul li a:hover {
  background: #0097CD;
}

#main p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 4</a>
          <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 5</a>
          <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Link 6</a>
          <ul class="fallback">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's it .. enjoy !!!

Comment: How does this help him make a multi level dropdown, anyway he says "bootstrap website" so it would make sense to use a bootstrap menu,

Comment: @bizzwebsite thank you for give reply ... its work properly .